# Federated SSO for salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, single-sign-on, federated-authentication, salesforce1-platform

I have configured Federated SSO with ADFS successfully. But we use sso on salesforce1 it will redirect to the full UI instead of the mobile UI. Salesforce document says we need to handle the relaystate in correct way. Can anyone knows how to handle the relaystate?

Answer (score 4):

The RelayState parameter is defined [here](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_forcecom_security_relaystate.htm)

The important thing to note is that it has now been changed as mentioned

> When a service provider initiates login, the default RelayState is now
>   /. In previous releases, the default RelayState was /home/home.jsp.

It is required that your IDP echoes this back correctly

> Ensure your IdP is properly receiving the RelayState param AND
>   correctly echoing the RelayState back per the SAML assertions (Request
>   / Response)

You should be able to log/ check the value of this param on the IDP end.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, Can we set the RelayState in salesforce itself?